# ключевое слово статик

Tags: java

Бывает нужно, чтобы переменная была в единственном экземпляре. Как, например, переменная `System.out` (статическая переменная `out` класса `System`).
Не пойму как понять в единственном экземпляре?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Это означает, что в памяти хранится единственный экземпляр переменной, которым пользуются все объекты. Например, незачем хранить для каждого объекта переменную  `Math.PI`, поскольку она для всех одинакова.

Допустим у нас есть класс `Circle` и в этом классе есть переменная `radius` и метод вычисления площади (который использует число пи).

Когда мы создаем объекты класса `Circle`, для каждого из них в памяти выделяется место. Поэтому в памяти хранится столько переменных `radius`, сколько у нас объектов (у каждого круга разный радиус). Но число пи одинаково для всех, поэтому его достаточно хранить один раз и не расходовать на нее память. Поэтому переменная `Math.PI` статична.

Другой пример: у нас есть класс Student, все студенты (объекты класса Student) учатся в одном вузе, поэтому значения переменной `university` у них идентичны, так что имеет смысл сделать поле university статичным, чтобы не хранить одно и то же в памяти в нескольких экземплярах.

Пример из немного другой области:
в семье в почтовом адресе "город, улица, квартира" статичны (у всех одинаковы), а имя (и иногда фамилия) адресата - нет.

Comment: Не очень понял ..(

Comment: Как понять пользуются все объекты?

Comment: добавил примеров

Comment: Исправьте на вузе вместо визе. Начало текста: Другой пример: ...

Comment: Пример с Circle, получается когда мы создаем объекты класса Circle, для каждого объекта хранится своя компания переменной radius? То есть 5 объектов, 5 переменных radius? Вы имеете ввиду что-то типо такого circle1.radius ... ? Ну получается каждый объект если будет вызывать переменную, то и будет у каждого объекта своя получается

Comment: Да, у каждого Circle своя переменная radius.

Comment: Пример с константой `PI` хороший. Другие примеры я бы убрал - они годятся только для ситуации "здесь и сейчас". А если студент меняет ВУЗ? Нарушается гибкость...

Comment: @ОлексійМоренець Да нормальный пример, он в каждом втором учебнике используется. Вуз или работодатель.